# Microsoft Graph API where use token generated by azure?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, graph, outlook, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph API or Outlook REST API to create events in user calendar throught ajax / rest calls.

But i don't know where i have to call the key generated by Azure when i registered my application in Azure Active Directory... And i don't know if i need to pass Client ID too.

I gave the following permissions to Microsoft Graph in Azure:

[image: microsoft graph permissions]

I don't know if these permissions are enough for what i want to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We often use Client id and keys to get accesstoken, when we have accesstoken we can access Azure. As to permission, based on your requirement, like `Access directory as the signed-in user`,`Read all users' full profiles` can be selected

Answer (score 0):

You could find permission details from [Permission scopes | Graph API concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes), also you can refer to [Office 365 Node.js Connect sample using Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-Connect) and  [Microsoft Graph service app sample using Node.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-App-only) from GitHub for more help.